# Adding Controller using Ado.Net Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am new for MVC, I am trying to add a control in my project.

- I added Entity Model in Model folder from database. It's name is `MyModel.edmx` and my entity's name is `MyEntities`.
- I followed this path: Controllers -> right click -> Add -> Controller. A window opened.
- In window:  I gave a name for my controller and I chose 'MVC Controller with read/write actions and views,using Entity Framework' for template.
- I think I must choose `ModelModel.edmx` as Model Class and 'MyEntites' as Data Context Class.

But `ModelModel.edmx` don't exist in Model class combobox.

I don't know if I did something wrong. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Try to type in the name of the model class manually. You have to build your solution before you can use scaffolding by the way.

Comment: I build my solution several times.But it doesn't work. By the way, I typed the name of model class manually but it gave this alert : 'The model type is invalid. Please select an item from list'.

Answer (score 0):

Do not choose `ModelModel.edmx` as model class,
Create a ViewModel that contains the properties that you need, use your service layer to populate the ViewModel and your controller will use that as the Model for its base.

Check this [Link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3)